# import does not work in subfolder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

When I use

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
require('./styles.css');
import App from './components/App';
import Test from './components/Test';

ReactDOM.render(
 <App />,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

webpack found the Test module however, in app component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Test from './components/Test';

export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Test />
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

import Test does not work it says:
ERROR in ./src/components/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Test'

it works when I use require though

```
var Test = require('./Test');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing from a wrong directory. From looking at your first code, you have both `App` and `Test` in the same `components` directory. The error comes because your import looks for a `components` folder inside the `components` folder. So if you want it to be imported into App, you should be specifying the relative path from your current folder. i.e) `./`

Try this in your App class or App.js file

```
import Test from './Test';
```